# How to initiate an html form from a button click in which the button then disappears and the form appears on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a quiz website and would like it to begin with a "begin quiz" button which then disappears and gives way to the first quiz question. All I have so far is the following:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Football Quiz Game</h1>
    <button type="button" name="mainButton" onClick = 
"this.style.visibility= 'hidden';">Begin Quiz!</button>

    <div class="firstQuestion">
    <h3>Who is the top all-time goalscorer in the UEFA Champions League? 
    </h3>
    <form class="question1">
      <input type="radio" id="Cristiano Ronaldo" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Cristiano Ronaldo">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Raul" name="topUCLscorer" value="Raul">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Raul</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Lionel Messi" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Lionel Messi">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Lionel Messi</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Karim Benzema" name="topUCLscorer" 
 value="Karim Benzema">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Karim Benzema</label>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for that. Try running the below snippet:

```js
const quizButton = document.querySelector('#quizButton');
const question = document.querySelector('.firstQuestion');

const beginQuiz = () => {
  quizButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  question.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Football Quiz Game</h1>
    <button id="quizButton" type="button" name="mainButton" onClick = 
"beginQuiz()">Begin Quiz!</button>

    <div class="firstQuestion" style="visibility: hidden">
    <h3>Who is the top all-time goalscorer in the UEFA Champions League? 
    </h3>
    <form class="question1" >
      <input type="radio" id="Cristiano Ronaldo" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Cristiano Ronaldo">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Raul" name="topUCLscorer" value="Raul">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Raul</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Lionel Messi" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Lionel Messi">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Lionel Messi</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Karim Benzema" name="topUCLscorer" 
 value="Karim Benzema">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Karim Benzema</label>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery see the below example.

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on("click", "#start", function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(".firstQuestion").show();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Football Quiz Game</h1>
    <button type="button" name="mainButton" id="start">Begin Quiz!</button>

    <div class="firstQuestion" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Who is the top all-time goalscorer in the UEFA Champions League? 
    </h3>
    <form class="question1">
      <input type="radio" id="Cristiano Ronaldo" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Cristiano Ronaldo">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Raul" name="topUCLscorer" value="Raul">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Raul</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Lionel Messi" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Lionel Messi">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Lionel Messi</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Karim Benzema" name="topUCLscorer" 
 value="Karim Benzema">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Karim Benzema</label>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo on code pen for you here: https://codepen.io/pen/WNrGqBd

You're on the right lines. To start with, i've hidden the first question using CSS, `display: none` and then added some javascript to make it appear on click. I've done this by adding classes to the relevant elements when you click the button. These classes contain the styles to change the display attribute of the elements they are applied to.

Answer (score 0):

I took the code and updated it on codepen. You can check it out in the link below. Hope it works...

```
    <body>
        <h1>Football Quiz Game</h1>
        <p>Once you are ready to begin, please click the button below. Goodluck</p>
        <button type="button" name="mainButton" id="mainButton">Begin Quiz!</button>

        <div class="firstQuestion">
            <h3>Who is the top all-time goalscorer in the UEFA Champions League?</h3>
            <form class="question1">
                <input type="radio" id="Cristiano Ronaldo" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Cristiano Ronaldo">
                <label for="topUCLscorer">Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
                <input type="radio" id="Raul" name="topUCLscorer" value="Raul">
                <label for="topUCLscorer">Raul</label>
                <input type="radio" id="Lionel Messi" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Lionel Messi">
                <label for="topUCLscorer">Lionel Messi</label>
                <input type="radio" id="Karim Benzema" name="topUCLscorer" 
 value="Karim Benzema">
                <label for="topUCLscorer">Karim Benzema</label>
            </form>
         </div>
     </body>
```

CSS

```
.firstQuestion {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const firstQuestion = document.querySelector('.firstQuestion');
const begin = document.querySelector('#mainButton');
begin.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  begin.style.display = 'none';
  firstQuestion.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Try this: https://codepen.io/dinakajoy/pen/eYJdqYx

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your own code and just added a simple javascript function at the end. I have only changed your onClick function

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Football Quiz Game</h1>
    <button type="button" id="mainButton" onClick = "show_form()" >Begin Quiz!</button>
    <div class="firstQuestion">
    <h3>Who is the top all-time goalscorer in the UEFA Champions League? 
    </h3>
    <form id="question1" style="visibility: hidden">
      <input type="radio" id="Cristiano Ronaldo" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Cristiano Ronaldo">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Raul" name="topUCLscorer" value="Raul">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Raul</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Lionel Messi" name="topUCLscorer" 
value="Lionel Messi">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Lionel Messi</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Karim Benzema" name="topUCLscorer" 
 value="Karim Benzema">
      <label for="topUCLscorer">Karim Benzema</label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function show_form(){
            document.getElementById("mainButton").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("question1").style.visibility="visible";
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```